# JSF + PrimeFaces 5 - Mesmo Estado da Página P/ Vários Usuários

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou com uma grande dificuldade em relação ao `PrimeFaces 5 + JSF`.

Tenho duas aplicações na empresa na qual trabalho e as mesmas rodando na *intranet*, porém quando alguém executa alguma coisa, consulta ou navega entre ambas as aplicação e um outro usuário a acessa, este novo usuário e todos os outros entram no sistema com esta mesma visão do antigo usuário.

> Ex: Usuário A -> Acessou a aba C e pesquisou os animais cadastrados no
>   sistema e o mesmo retornou uma lista; Usuário B e C -> Acessam ou
>   Logam o mesmo sistema, e já entram na Aba C, visualizando a lista de
>   animais pesquisados pelo Usuário A;

Resumo: Os usuários que estão sendo logados ou acessando o sistema, entram na aplicação visualizando o último estado da mesma.

P.S O meu MB está anotado como @RequestScoped

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

    <f:view>
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <title>Escala de Plantão</title>

            <script>
                PrimeFaces.locales['pt'] = {
                    closeText: 'Fechar',
                    prevText: 'Anterior',
                    nextText: 'Próximo',
                    currentText: 'Começo',
                    monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
                    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
                    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S'],
                    weekHeader: 'Semana',
                    firstDay: 0,
                    isRTL: false,
                    showMonthAfterYear: false,
                    yearSuffix: '',
                    timeOnlyTitle: 'Só Horas',
                    timeText: 'Tempo',
                    hourText: 'Hora',
                    minuteText: 'Minuto',
                    secondText: 'Segundo',
                    ampm: false,
                    month: 'Mês',
                    week: 'Semana',
                    day: 'Dia',
                    allDayText: 'Todo o Dia'
                };
            </script>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="form" style="height:100%;">
                <p:growl id="msg" life="5000" />

                <p:layout fullPage="true">
                    <p:layoutUnit  position="west" size="400">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" border="1" >
                            <p:panel id="panelInclusao" header="Inclusão" style="height:95%;border: 0px;">

                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" cellpadding="5"  >

                                    <p:outputLabel for="disciplina" value="Disciplina: " />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="disciplina" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.idDisciplina}" valueChangeListener="#{plantaoControllerMB.onChangeDisciplina}" style="width:100%;">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma disciplina" itemValue="" />                    
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{plantaoControllerMB.listaDisciplina}" />
                                        <p:ajax event="change" update="colaborador" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                                    <p:outputLabel for="colaborador" value="Colaborador: " />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="colaborador" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.idColaborador}" style="width:100%;">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um colaborador" itemValue="" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{plantaoControllerMB.listaColaborador}" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                                    <p:outputLabel for="intervalo" value="Intervalo: " />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="intervalo" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.idIntervaloPlantao}" style="width:100%;">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um intervalo" itemValue="" />                    
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{plantaoControllerMB.listaIntervaloPlantao}" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                                    <p:outputLabel for="data" value="Dia do Plantão:" />
                                    <p:calendar id="data" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.dataPlantao}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" effect="fold" style="width:100%;" locale="pt" />

                                    <br/>
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;">
                                        <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="btnSalvar" type="submit" ajax="true" process="@form" actionListener="#{plantaoControllerMB.salvarPlantao}" update="msg, tabelaRegistros" style="width:100%" />
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:panel>
                        </h:panelGrid>


                        <h:panelGrid columns="2"  border="1"  style="width:100%;">
                            <p:panel id="panelConsulta" header="Consulta" style="height:95%;border: 0px;">
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" cellpadding="5"  >

                                    <p:outputLabel for="disciplinaPesquisa" value="Disciplina: " />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="disciplinaPesquisa" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.idDisciplinaPesquisa}"  valueChangeListener="#{plantaoControllerMB.onChangeDisciplinaPesquisa}" style="width:100%;">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Filtro de Pesquisa" itemValue="" />                    
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{plantaoControllerMB.listaDisciplinaPesquisa}" />
                                        <p:ajax event="change" update="colaboradorPesquisa" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                                    <p:outputLabel for="colaboradorPesquisa" value="Colaborador: " />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="colaboradorPesquisa" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.idColaboradorPesquisa}" style="width:100%;">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Filtro de Pesquisa" itemValue="" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{plantaoControllerMB.listaColaboradorPesquisa}" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                                    <p:outputLabel for="dataInicioMes" value="Data Início: " />
                                    <p:calendar id="dataInicioMes" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.dataInicioMes}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" effect="fold" style="width:100%;" locale="pt" />

                                    <p:outputLabel for="dataFimMes" value="Data Fim: " />
                                    <p:calendar id="dataFimMes" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.dataFimMes}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" effect="fold" style="width:100%;" locale="pt" />

                                    <br/>
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" >
                                        <p:commandButton value="Pesquisar" id="btnPesquisar" type="submit" ajax="true" process="@form" actionListener="#{plantaoControllerMB.pesquisarPlantao}" update="msg, tabelaRegistros" style="width:100%"  />
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:panel>
                        </h:panelGrid>      

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" border="1" style="width:100%;" >
                            <p:panel id="panelRelatorio" header="Relatório" style="height:95%;border: 0px;">

                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" cellpadding="4"  >

                                    <p:outputLabel for="dataInicio" value="Data Início da Semana: (Segunda)" />
                                    <p:calendar id="dataInicio" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.dataInicioSemana}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" effect="fold" style="width:100%;" locale="pt" />

                                    <p:outputLabel for="tiporelatorio" value="Tipo de Relatório: " />
                                    <p:selectOneRadio id="tiporelatorio" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.tipoRelatorio}" >
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="PDF" itemValue="PDF" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="EXCEL" itemValue="EXCEL" />
                                    </p:selectOneRadio>

                                    <br/>
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;">
                                        <p:commandButton value="Gerar Plantão Consolidado" id="btnGerarPlantao" ajax="false" actionListener="#{plantaoControllerMB.getSampleReportPDF}" update="msg" >
                                            <p:fileDownload value="#{plantaoControllerMB.streamedContent}" />
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:panel>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:layoutUnit>

                    <p:layoutUnit id="layoutUnit2" position="center">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
                            <p:dataTable id="tabelaRegistros" var="registro" value="#{plantaoControllerMB.listaRegistroVO}"  selection="#{plantaoControllerMB.listSelectedExcluirVO}" rowKey="#{registro.idRegistro}"
                                         editable="false" style="margin-bottom:20px" emptyMessage="Sem Registros."  paginator="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    Lista dos Plantonistas
                                </f:facet>
                                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>

                                <p:column headerText="Dia">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{registro.dataPlantao}"  style="text-align:center;width:100%" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="Intervalo">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{registro.intervaloPlantao}" style="text-align:center; width:100%" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="Disciplina">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{registro.nomeDisciplina}" style="text-align:center; width:100%" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="Colaborador">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{registro.nomeColaborador}" style="text-align:center; width:100%" />
                                </p:column>

                                <f:facet name="footer" >
                                    <p:column style="width:16px">
                                        <p:commandButton value="Excluir" id="btnExcluir" type="submit" ajax="true" process="@form" actionListener="#{plantaoControllerMB.excluirRegistroEscalaPlantao}" update=":form:msg, tabelaRegistros"/>
                                    </p:column>
                                </f:facet>    

                            </p:dataTable>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                </p:layout>         
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

```
package com.iedacr.plantao.controller;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.iedacr.plantao.spring.model.Colaborador;
import com.iedacr.plantao.spring.model.ColaboradorIntervaloPlantao;
import com.iedacr.plantao.spring.model.Disciplina;
import com.iedacr.plantao.spring.model.IntervaloPlantao;
import com.iedacr.plantao.spring.model.RegistroVO;
import com.iedacr.plantao.spring.service.PlantaoService;
import com.iedacr.plantao.util.ConnectionFactoryJDBC;
import com.iedacr.plantao.util.ReportUtils;
import com.iedacr.plantao.util.TiposRelatorio;

@Controller
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "plantaoControllerMB")
public class PlantaoControllerMB implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8257510266299290234L;

    @Autowired
    private PlantaoService plantaoService;

    private ColaboradorIntervaloPlantao colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO;

    private List<SelectItem> listaIntervaloPlantao;

    private List<SelectItem> listaColaborador;

    private List<SelectItem> listaDisciplina;

    private List<SelectItem> listaDisciplinaPesquisa;

    private List<SelectItem> listaColaboradorPesquisa;

    private String idIntervaloPlantao;

    private String idDisciplina;

    private String idColaborador;

    private Date dataPlantao;

    private List<RegistroVO> listaRegistroVO;

    private List<RegistroVO> listSelectedExcluirVO;

    private Date dataInicioSemana;

    private StreamedContent streamedContent;

    private String tipoRelatorio;

    private String idDisciplinaPesquisa;

    private String idColaboradorPesquisa;

    private Date dataInicioMes;

    private Date dataFimMes;

    public void addMessageInfo(String summary) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary, null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    public void addMessageError(String summary) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, summary, null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        listaDisciplina = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        listaDisciplinaPesquisa = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        for (Disciplina disciplina : plantaoService.getListDisciplina()) {

            listaDisciplina.add(new SelectItem(disciplina.getId(), disciplina.getNome()));
            listaDisciplinaPesquisa.add(new SelectItem(disciplina.getId(), disciplina.getNome()));

        }

        listaIntervaloPlantao = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        for (IntervaloPlantao intervaloPlantao : plantaoService.getListIntervalo()) {

            listaIntervaloPlantao.add(new SelectItem(intervaloPlantao.getId(), intervaloPlantao.getIntervalo()));

        }

        listaColaborador = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        listaColaboradorPesquisa = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        listaRegistroVO = new ArrayList<RegistroVO>();

        listSelectedExcluirVO = new ArrayList<RegistroVO>();

    }

    public String validarCamposInclusao() {

        if (idDisciplina == null || idDisciplina.isEmpty()) {

            return "Erro: Favor informar o Disciplina";
        }

        if (idColaborador == null || idColaborador.isEmpty()) {

            return "Erro: Favor informar o Colaborador";
        }

        if (idIntervaloPlantao == null || idIntervaloPlantao.isEmpty()) {

            return "Erro: Favor informar o Intervalo do Plantão";
        }

        if (dataPlantao == null) {

            return "Erro: Favor informar o Dia do Plantão";
        }

        return null;

    }

    public void salvarPlantao() {

        String result = validarCamposInclusao();

        if (result != null) {

            addMessageError(result);
            return;
        }

        SimpleDateFormat dataf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String strDataPlantaoFormatada = dataf.format(dataPlantao).toString();

        /*if(plantaoService.isExistePlantonistaByDay(new BigDecimal(idColaborador), strDataPlantaoFormatada)){

         addMessageError("Já existe um plantão cadastrado para este colaborador no dia informado ");

         } else{*/
        colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO = new ColaboradorIntervaloPlantao();
        colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO.setDataPlantao(new java.sql.Date(dataPlantao.getTime()));
        colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO.setColaborador(plantaoService.getColaboradorById(new BigDecimal(idColaborador)));
        colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO.setIntervaloPlantao(plantaoService.getIntervaloPlantaoById(new BigDecimal(idIntervaloPlantao)));

        ColaboradorIntervaloPlantao entidadePersistida = plantaoService.save(colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO);

        RegistroVO regVO = new RegistroVO();
        regVO.setDataPlantao(dataf.format(colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO.getDataPlantao()));
        regVO.setIdRegistro(entidadePersistida.getId().toString());
        regVO.setIntervaloPlantao(colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO.getIntervaloPlantao().getIntervalo());
        regVO.setNomeColaborador(colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO.getColaborador().getNome());
        regVO.setNomeDisciplina(colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO.getColaborador().getDisciplina().getNome());
        listaRegistroVO.add(regVO);

        addMessageInfo("Plantão de " + colaboradorIntervaloPlantaoVO.getColaborador().getNome() + " foi salvo com sucesso! ");

        //}
    }

    public void gerarPlantaoConsolidado() throws ViewExpiredException {

        if (dataInicioSemana == null) {

            addMessageError("Erro: Informe a data de início da uma semana para gerar o plantão consolidado");

            return;

        }

        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Plantao.jasper");

        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        GregorianCalendar gregorian = new GregorianCalendar();
        gregorian.setTime(dataInicioSemana);

        if (gregorian.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != 2) {

            addMessageError("Erro: A data início da semana não corresponde a segunda-feira.");

            return;

        }

        SimpleDateFormat dataf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        parametros.put("DATA_INICIO", dataf.format(dataInicioSemana).toString());

        gregorian.add(gregorian.DATE, 6);
        parametros.put("DATA_FIM", dataf.format(gregorian.getTime()).toString());

        {

            parametros.put("SEGUNDA", dataf.format(dataInicioSemana).toString());

            gregorian.setTime(dataInicioSemana);

            gregorian.add(gregorian.DATE, 1);
            parametros.put("TERCA", dataf.format(gregorian.getTime()).toString());

            gregorian.add(gregorian.DATE, 1);
            parametros.put("QUARTA", dataf.format(gregorian.getTime()).toString());

            gregorian.add(gregorian.DATE, 1);
            parametros.put("QUINTA", dataf.format(gregorian.getTime()).toString());

            gregorian.add(gregorian.DATE, 1);
            parametros.put("SEXTA", dataf.format(gregorian.getTime()).toString());

            gregorian.add(gregorian.DATE, 1);
            parametros.put("SABADO", dataf.format(gregorian.getTime()).toString());

            gregorian.add(gregorian.DATE, 1);
            parametros.put("DOMINGO", dataf.format(gregorian.getTime()).toString());

        }

        try {

            // abre o relatório
            ReportUtils.openReport("Plantonistas da Fiscalização", inputStream, parametros,
                    ConnectionFactoryJDBC.getPlantaoConnection());

            addMessageInfo(" Plantão consolidado gerado com sucesso! ");

        } catch (SQLException exc) {

            addMessageError("Erro na consulta do relatório.");

        } catch (JRException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void excluirRegistroEscalaPlantao() {

        if (listSelectedExcluirVO == null || listSelectedExcluirVO.isEmpty()) {

            addMessageError("É necessário selecionar ao menos um colaborador para efetuar o processo de exclusão!");

        } else {

            List<RegistroVO> listVO = new ArrayList<RegistroVO>();
            listVO.addAll(listaRegistroVO);

            for (int i = 0; i < listVO.size(); i++) {

                for (RegistroVO tempExcluir : listSelectedExcluirVO) {

                    if (tempExcluir.getIdRegistro().equals(listVO.get(i).getIdRegistro())) {

                        listVO.remove(i);
                        plantaoService.delete(plantaoService.getById(new BigDecimal(tempExcluir.getIdRegistro())));

                    }
                }

            }

            listaRegistroVO.clear();
            listaRegistroVO.addAll(listVO);

            addMessageInfo("A exclusão dos registros selecionados foi realizada com sucesso!");
        }

    }

    public List<SelectItem> getColaboradoresByDiciplina(String idDisciplina) {

        listaColaborador.clear();

        for (Colaborador colaborador : plantaoService.getColaboradoresByDiciplina(new BigDecimal(idDisciplina))) {

            listaColaborador.add(new SelectItem(colaborador.getId(), colaborador.getNome()));
        }

        return listaColaborador;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getColaboradoresByDiciplinaPesquisa(String idDisciplina) {

        listaColaboradorPesquisa.clear();

        for (Colaborador colaborador : plantaoService.getColaboradoresByDiciplina(new BigDecimal(idDisciplina))) {

            listaColaboradorPesquisa.add(new SelectItem(colaborador.getId(), colaborador.getNome()));
        }

        return listaColaboradorPesquisa;
    }

    public void onChangeDisciplina(ValueChangeEvent e) {

        if (e.getNewValue() != null) {
            this.listaColaborador = getColaboradoresByDiciplina(e.getNewValue().toString());
        }
    }

    public void onChangeDisciplinaPesquisa(ValueChangeEvent e) {

        if (e.getNewValue() != null) {
            this.listaColaboradorPesquisa = getColaboradoresByDiciplinaPesquisa(e.getNewValue().toString());
        }
    }

    public void pesquisarPlantao() {

        RegistroVO regVO = new RegistroVO();

        regVO.setIdDisciplina(idDisciplinaPesquisa);
        regVO.setIdColaborador(idColaboradorPesquisa);
        //regVO.setIdIntervaloPlantao(idIntervaloPlantao);

        if (dataInicioMes != null) {

            SimpleDateFormat dataf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String strDataPlantaoFormatada = dataf.format(dataInicioMes).toString();

            regVO.setDataInicioMes(strDataPlantaoFormatada);

        } else {

            regVO.setDataInicioMes(null);
        }

        if (dataFimMes != null) {

            SimpleDateFormat dataf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String strDataPlantaoFormatada = dataf.format(dataFimMes).toString();

            regVO.setDataFimMes(strDataPlantaoFormatada);

        } else {

            regVO.setDataFimMes(null);
        }

        listaRegistroVO.clear();
        listaRegistroVO.addAll(plantaoService.pesquisarPlantao(regVO));

    }

    public StreamedContent exportFileToPDF() {

        return streamedContent;
    }

    public StreamedContent getSampleReportPDF() {

        streamedContent = null;

        return streamedContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostre o código do seu managed bean - pelo menos a parte que entrega esta lista cujo estado é mantido entre as sessões. Se o MB é RequestScoped, então o estado está sendo mantido em outro objeto.

Comment: Tem bastante código aí e você não apontou o que exatamente mantém estado entre as sessões. O bean injetado *PlantaoService* parece ter um escopo maior do que deveria (deve estar com escopo de aplicação) ou uiliza o estado de um outro bean com escopo de aplicação - ou seja, tem que analisar o código de *PlantaoService*. Mas você já entendeu o ponto: a partir da lista que está mantendo estado siga todos os objetos utilizados e descubra qual deles está com escopo de aplicação e então reduza o escopo ou limpe o estado a cada requisição (a segunda opção é difícil porque precisaria ser thread safe).